# Infinitely many moons, or one ring to bring them all, a limit to bind it?

Tags: limits, physics, analytic-geometry

The Kanagy clan makes its home on a distant planet of mass $M_p$ with $k$ moons. Suppose the moons are identical with mass $m$. Furthermore, these moons share a common circular orbit on an orbital plane. The circular orbits are at distance $L$ from the center of the planet and the moons are evenly spaced.

1. What is the speed $v(k)$ of the lunar orbits for a fixed, but finite, value of $k$?
2. Suppose we hold $km=M_m$ fixed as $k \rightarrow \infty$, what is the limiting value of $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}v(k)$ in this context?

My ideal solution to this problem addresses $(1.)$ by vector analysis paired with the equation of motion for constant speed circular motion. Often cases $k=2$ or $k=3$ are given as homework problems in first semester university physics. I've found an expression for this in a previous attempt, but I'd rather not include it here for fear of biasing the reader. Next, the solution continues to $(2.)$, when I attempted to compute the limit directly it was rather involved. However, by intuition, I know the answer should easily derive from Newton's Law of Gravitation as follows:
$$ \frac{M_mv^2}{L}= \frac{GM_mM_p}{L^2} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad v = \sqrt{\frac{GM_p}{L}} $$

> Given the preceding discussion, show show $v(k) \rightarrow \sqrt{\frac{GM_p}{L}}$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. Alternatively, prove my intuition is incorrect.

Incidentally, I gave this as a bonus problem on a final exam in my university physics course. I had a student pretty well solve $(1.)$, but $(2.)$ I've not yet cracked. It is assumed that classical mechanics applies to this problem and any relativistic effects may be neglected.

Comment: Presumably the planet is assumed to be spherical (and thus can be regarded as a point mass).  Real planets would be deformed by tidal forces...

Comment: @RobertIsrael precisely, this is a boring spherical planet, not some oblate spheroid like our home.

Comment: Just curious: who or what are the Kanagy clan?

Comment: @RobertIsrael The Kanagy clan is a collection of Naruto-loving, long-board riding noble individuals. Characteristically, members of this clan could earn an A in most courses, but due various interactions and obligations keep this ability secret. I think of it as academic camouflage, members of this clan disguise themselves as B/C students when there true standing is A. Just what is a Kanagy? This I only partially understand.

Comment: @RobertIsrael So, after all this, I'm curious where my intuition fails. It seems this moons should morph into a ring in the described limit and I don't see error with my calculation of the speed to the orbiting ring. So, perhaps something is unphysical about the limiting process? This result I find curious, usually I can build physical results from limits of this sort without bizzare results like the one found here. I must be missing something.

Comment: The ring has finite linear density, but since its cross-section is $0$ it has infinite spatial density.  In order to get a finite result, you'd need a ring of nonzero thickness, or perhaps a ribbon.

Comment: @RobertIsrael interesting, so if I smear out the moons in the limit then this infinity disappears. I don't see how just yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The centre of mass of the system is at the planet, which we can thus assume is stationary.  If we number the moons $0$ to $k-1$, moon $0$ sees an angle 
$\theta_j = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \dfrac{j \pi}{k}$  between moon $j$ and the planet, and the distance from moon $0$ to moon $j$ is $2 L \sin(j \pi/k)$.  So the 
component in the direction of the planet of the gravitational acceleration of moon $0$ due to moon $j$ is $\cos(\theta_j) G m/(2 L \sin(j \pi/k))^2 = G m/(4 L^2 \sin(j \pi/k))$.  The net gravitational acceleration (directed toward the planet) due to all the other moons is then
$$  \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dfrac{G m}{4 L^2 \sin(j \pi/k)}
=  \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dfrac{G M_m}{4 k L^2 \sin(j \pi/k)}
> \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \dfrac{G M_m}{4 L^2 \pi j}$$ 
But that goes to $+\infty$ as $k \to \infty$.  So we must also have $v(k) \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, it's been a crazy week. I think I follow your argument to a particular point. My question is how did you simplify $\cos (\theta_j)$ and the $(2L\sin( j\pi/k))^2$ term? By my calculation, $\cos( \theta_j)=d/(2L)$ where $d$ is the distance from moon 0 to moon $j$. Ah, good, I do agree with your post. Excellent. My only lingering doubt is that when I previously did it I found it necessary to give different arguments for even and odd numbers of moons.